# REGEX - problema com validação

Tags: java, regex

Preciso fazer a seguinte validação:

> **a-z** (maiúsculos e minúsculos), **hífen** (-), **apóstrofo** (\'),  **espaço** ( ) e **números** (0-9)

Para isso fiz o seguinte:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {
    /** validação */
    public static final String PATTERN= "^[A-Z|a-z|0-9| |Á-Ú|á-ú|Ã-Ũ|ã-ũ|'|-]+$";
    /** testes positivos */
    public static String[] itens = { "á é í ó ú", "ã ẽ ĩ õ ũ", "Á È Ĩ Ã ó", "aeiou", "abc def ghi", "um 23 45",
                                     "Um - 2 - tres quatro", "Um' 2  três' quatro", "maçã", "Â Ê Î ô û", "á Ae Éi Ĩô O"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(final String s : itens) {
            boolean b = isValid(s);
            System.out.println(b+" : "+s);
        }
    }
    public static boolean isValid(final String string) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
        return m.matches();
    }
}
```

Tecnicamente é para todos os itens retornarem **true**.

Mas a seguinte String `ã ẽ ĩ õ ũ`, retorna **false**.

Como posso fazer esta validação?

[Segue o link do Ideone](https://ideone.com/1TXovl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você precisa usar são [regex baseadas em unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html). Os caracteres acentuados não tem uma ordem que faça lá muito sentido para meros mortais, e portanto, coisas como `á-ú` não funciona.

A classe `\p{Letter}` (ou simplesmente `\p{L}`) representa letras em geral. Porém, ela também abarca letras não latinas (alfabetos cirílico, grego, hebraico, chinês, árabe, etc.)

A classe `\p{IsLatin}` considera os caracteres latinos. Entretanto, símbolos especiais (parênteses, colchetes, asterisco, porcentagem, etc) também são considerados caraceteres especiais.

Assim sendo, a solução é usar [a intersecção desses dois conjuntos](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html) com `[\p{L}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]` ou com `[\p{IsLatin}&&[\p{L}]]`.

Eis o código resultante:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class RegexTest {

    /* Validação. */
    public static final Pattern PADRAO = Pattern.compile(
            "^[([\\p{L}&&[\\p{IsLatin}]]|0-9| |'|-]+$");

    /* Testes positivos. */
    public static String[] positivos = {
            "á é í ó ú",
            "ã ẽ ĩ õ ũ",
            "Á È Ĩ Ã ó",
            "aeiou",
            "abc def ghi",
            "um 23 45",
            "Um - 2 - tres quatro",
            "Um' 2  três' quatro",
            "maçã",
            "Â Ê Î ô û",
            "á Ae Éi Ĩô O",
            "O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma",
            "áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙäëïöüÄËÏÖÜâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãẽĩñõũÃẼĨÑÕŨçÇ"
    };

    /* Testes negativos. */
    public static String[] negativos = {
            ".",
            "*",
            "/",
            "<",
            "≃",
            "^",
            "~",
            "()",
            "#",
            "中国"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (final String s : positivos) {
            boolean b = isValid(s);
            System.out.println(b + (b ? " ok - " : " oops - ") + s);
        }
        for (final String s : negativos) {
            boolean b = isValid(s);
            System.out.println(b + (b ? " oops - " : " ok - ") + s);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValid(final String string) {
        return PADRAO.matcher(string).matches();
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
true ok - á é í ó ú
true ok - ã ẽ ĩ õ ũ
true ok - Á È Ĩ Ã ó
true ok - aeiou
true ok - abc def ghi
true ok - um 23 45
true ok - Um - 2 - tres quatro
true ok - Um' 2  três' quatro
true ok - maçã
true ok - Â Ê Î ô û
true ok - á Ae Éi Ĩô O
true ok - O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma
true ok - áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙäëïöüÄËÏÖÜâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãẽĩñõũÃẼĨÑÕŨçÇ
false ok - .
false ok - *
false ok - /
false ok - <
false ok - ≃
false ok - ^
false ok - ~
false ok - ()
false ok - #
false ok - 中国
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](http://ideone.com/n7f532)

Ah, mais um detalhezinho: O objeto da classe `Pattern` é custoso de ser construído, porém ele é imutável, *thread-safe* e pode ser reutilizado a vontade uma vez que é criado. Assim sendo, sempre prefira construí-lo no escopo estático se possível, evitando criar e recriar o mesmo `Pattern` várias vezes.

Comment: Perfeito! muito obrigado!

Comment: up pela ótima explicação