# Validar nome e sobrenome com expressão regular

Tags: regex

Preciso criar uma expressão regular que valide se o formato do nome e sobrenome do usuário são válidos, por exemplo:

```
Maria Silva | true
Maria  Silva | false
Maria silva | false
maria Silva | false
MariaSilva  | false
```

Ou seja ele só poderá aceitar quando o Nome e o Sobrenome estiver em letras maiúsculas e com apenas um espaço entre as palavras, tentei utilizar esta expressão:

```
[A-Z][a-z].* [A-Z][a-z].*
```

Porém assim esta aceitando modos que não se encaixam no padrão que eu preciso.

Comment: Não seria melhor aplicar titled case no backend? `Maria Silva` é simples já pensou quando for algo como `Maria da Silva e Silva`?

Comment: @rray, como Poderia fazer isso? Poderia postar uma resposta com um exemplo?

Comment: O @Sergio matou a charada. O ponto asterisco que está dando o problema

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu vi, porém a questão levantada pelo rray faz sentido

Comment: Sim, faz total sentido. E ainda pode pegar nomes estrangeiros como `McFarlene` que tem minúsculas e maiúsculas misturadas. Mas isso depende do seu universo de dados o como tratar

Comment: Porém não estou conseguindo encontrar um exemplo de como utilizar o `titled case` para testar, se tiverem um exemplo para darem

Comment: @danieltakeshi mas o que o rray citou seria esse exemplo de nome `Maria da Silva e Silva` e assim na sua expressão também não pega

Comment: E quanto a nomes com acentos ou com mais de dois componentes tais como "*Getúlio Dornelles Vargas*"?

Comment: @VictorStafusa exato, porém não encontrei nenhum exemplo de como suprir essa necessidade, tu teria algum exemplo?

Comment: E que tal "*Juscelino Kubitschek de Oliveira*"? As conjunções também podem ser minúsculas. Ocorre que você tem que definir o que é que você quer. Você quer validar se a entrada é um nome completo válido?

Comment: O link bem bacana para ajudar no desenvolvimento de novos padrões... https://www.piazinho.com.br/ed5/exemplos.html#163

Answer (score 18, accepted):

O problema é estares a usar o ponto, que é para qualquer caracter excepto terminadores de linha. Se tirares já vai funcionar.

> `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)

```js
function valida(nome){
return !!nome.match(/[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*/);
}

const testes = ["Maria Silva", "Maria  Silva", "Maria silva", "maria Silva", "MariaSilva"];
const resultados = testes.map(valida);
console.log(resultados);
```

---

Regex para nomes é sempre complicado pois há nomes de países mais complexos que Rosa ou Maria. Por exemplo "Åsa Ekström", "John Ó Súilleabháin" ou "Gregor O'Sulivan".

Nestes casos a regex pode ficar absurdamente complexa. E é dificil acertar todas as variantes... ainda assim uma sugestão pode ser

```js
function valida(nome) {
  return !!nome.match(/^[A-ZÀ-Ÿ][A-zÀ-ÿ']+\s([A-zÀ-ÿ']\s?)*[A-ZÀ-Ÿ][A-zÀ-ÿ']+$/) + ' ' + nome;
}

const testes = ["Maria Silva", "Åsa Ekström", "John Ó Súilleabháin", "Gregor O'Sulivan", "Maria  Silva", "Maria silva", "maria Silva", "MariaSilva"];
const resultados = testes.map(valida);
console.log(resultados);
```

Comment: Eu não consegui visualizar esse ponto! Olhos de águia!

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado

Comment: @Miguel só para o teste ficar mais bonito com `true|false` e não com o resultado todo do `.match` :P

Answer (score 20):

## TL;DR

A regex é:

> `^(?:[\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]])(?:(?:')?(?:[\p{Ll}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]))+(?:\-(?:[\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]])(?:(?:')?(?:[\p{Ll}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]))+)*(?: (?:(?:e|y|de(?:(?: la| las| lo| los))?|do|dos|da|das|del|van|von|bin|le) )?(?:(?:(?:d'|D'|O'|Mc|Mac|al\-))?(?:[\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]])(?:(?:')?(?:[\p{Ll}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]))+|(?:[\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]])(?:(?:')?(?:[\p{Ll}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]))+(?:\-(?:[\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]])(?:(?:')?(?:[\p{Ll}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]))+)*))+(?: (?:Jr\.|II|III|IV))?$`

De acordo com a página do [regex unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), o `\p{IsLatin}` é suportado pelo Java, C#, PHP, Perl e Ruby. Você pode testar esta expressão regular no site do [regexplanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

## Explicação detalhada

Primeiro, vamos definir algumas regras para nomes completos:

- Ao menos dois nomes (embora existam pessoas que só tenham um nome, como por exemplo, o [emperador Akihito do Japão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akihito), mas vamos deixá-las de fora).
- Exatamente um espaço separando nomes.
- Um mesmo nome ou sobrenome pode ser composto, separado por hífen. Pode haver mais de um hífen (ex: "[*Luís Augusto de Saxe-Coburgo-Gota*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lu%C3%ADs_Augusto_de_Saxe-Coburgo-Gota)")
- Aceitando acentos.
- A inicial de cada palavra deve ser maiúscula e as demais letras minúsculas.
- Deve aceitar conjunções inteiramente minúsculas.
- Sobrenomes como "*O'Brian*", "*d'Alembert*" e "*McDonald*" devem ser aceitos.
- Não podem haver duas ou mais conjunções seguidas (ex: "*do da*"). Entretanto "[*María Antonieta de las Nieves*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mar%C3%ADa_Antonieta_de_las_Nieves)" é um nome válido, então a conjunção pode ser composta.
- Nomes e sobrenomes (mas não conjunções) devem ter ao menos duas letras.
- Apóstrofos entre letras são permitidos (ex: "[*Samuel Eto'o*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Eto'o)"). Mas não podem estar no começo ou no final da palavra e nem estarem consecutivos.
- Alguns nomes tais como "[*Martin Luther King Jr.*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Luther_King_Jr.)" e "[*William Henry Gates III*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Gates)" tem sufixos.

Para fazer isso com regex, vamos estipular o seguinte:

- As conjunções são "*e*", "*y*", "*de*", "*de lo*", "*de los*", "*de la*", "*de las*", "*do*", "*dos*", "*da*", "*das*", "*del*", "*van*", "*von*", "*bin*" e "*le*".
- Sobrenomes podem ser prefixados com "*d'*", "*D'*", "*O'*", "*Mc*", "*Mac*" ou "*al-*".
- Os sufixos são "*Jr.*", "*II*", "*III*" e "*IV*".

Então, a estrutura do nome seria essa:

```
NOME-COMPLETO := PRENOME (espaço [CONJUNÇÃO espaço] SOBRENOME)+ (espaço SUFIXO)?
SOBRENOME := (PREFIXO)? NOME | PRENOME
PRENOME := NOME ("-" NOME)*
NOME := MAIÚSCULA (("'")? MINÚSCULA)+
PREFIXO := "d'" | "O'" | "Mc" | "Mac" | "al-"
SUFIXO = "Jr." | "II" | "III" | "IV"
CONJUNÇÃO := "e" | "y" | "de" (" lo" | " los" | " la" | " las")? | "do" | "dos" | "da" | "das" | "del" | "van" | "von" | "bin" | "le"
MAIÚSCULA := [\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]
MINÚSCULA := [\p{Ll}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]
```

Essa regra `[\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]` é responsável por reconhecer um caractere que esteja na intersecção entre o conjunto de letras maiúsculas (`\p{Lu}`) e caracteres latinos (`\p{IsLatin}`). Logo, isso aceita também caracteres latinos acentuados maiúsculos. O (`\p{Ll}`) é para letras minúsculas. Veja mais sobre as classes de caracteres [nesta outra resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/227571/132) e também [neste link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

O conjunto de regras acima pode ser lido como uma gramática livre de contexto. No entanto, ela pode ser reduzida em uma expressão regular, vez que não há regras recursivas nela. Para isso, basta substituir as regras que estão abaixo nas regras acima.

Entretanto, como construir essa regex manualmente é um processo chato, trabalhoso, muito propenso a erros e a regex resultante é uma monstruosidade, principalmente se você tiver que alterar alguma coisa de vez em quando, fiz um programa que constrói a regex correspondente e também testa ela com vários nomes diferentes. Eis o programa (em Java):

## Construindo e testando a regex

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

class TesteRegex {

    private static final String MAIUSCULA = "(?:[\\p{Lu}&&[\\p{IsLatin}]])";
    private static final String MINUSCULA = "(?:[\\p{Ll}&&[\\p{IsLatin}]])";

    private static final String PREFIXO = choice("d'", "D'", "O'", "Mc", "Mac", "al\\-");
    private static final String SUFIXO = choice("Jr\\.", "II", "III", "IV");
    private static final String CONJUNCAO = choice("e", "y", "de" + opt(choice(" la", " las", " lo", " los")), "do", "dos", "da", "das", "del", "van", "von", "bin", "le");
    private static final String NOME = MAIUSCULA + plus(opt("'") + MINUSCULA);
    private static final String PRENOME = NOME + star("\\-" + NOME);
    private static final String SOBRENOME = choice(opt(PREFIXO) + NOME, PRENOME);
    private static final String NOME_COMPLETO = "^" + PRENOME + plus(" " + opt(CONJUNCAO + " ") + SOBRENOME) + opt(" " + SUFIXO) + "$";

    private static String opt(String in) {
        return "(?:" + in + ")?";
    }

    private static String plus(String in) {
        return "(?:" + in + ")+";
    }

    private static String star(String in) {
        return "(?:" + in + ")*";
    }

    private static String choice(String... in) {
        StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("|", "(?:", ")");
        for (String s : in) {
            sj.add(s);
        }
        return sj.toString();
    }

    private static final Pattern REGEX_NOME = Pattern.compile(NOME_COMPLETO);

    private static final String[] NOMES = {
        "Maria Silva",
        "Pedro Carlos",
        "Luiz Antônio",
        "Albert Einstein",
        "João Doria",
        "Barack Obama",
        "Friedrich von Hayek",
        "Ludwig van Beethoven",
        "Jeanne d'Arc",
        "Saddam Hussein al-Tikriti",
        "Osama bin Mohammed bin Awad bin Laden",
        "Luís Inácio Lula da Silva",
        "Getúlio Dornelles Vargas",
        "Juscelino Kubitschek de Oliveira",
        "Jean-Baptiste le Rond d'Alembert",
        "Pierre-Simon Laplace",
        "Hans Christian Ørsted",
        "Joseph Louis Gay-Lussac",
        "Scarlett O'Hara",
        "Ronald McDonald",
        "María Antonieta de las Nieves",
        "Pedro de Alcântara Francisco António João Carlos Xavier de Paula Miguel Rafael Joaquim José Gonzaga Pascoal Cipriano Serafim",
        "Luís Augusto Maria Eudes de Saxe-Coburgo-Gota",
        "Martin Luther King Jr.",
        "William Henry Gates III",
        "John William D'Arcy",
        "John D'Largy",
        "Samuel Eto'o",
        "Åsa Ekström",
        "Gregor O'Sulivan",
        "Ítalo Gonçalves"
    };

    private static final String[] LIXOS = {
        "",
        "Maria",
        "Maria-Silva",
        "Marcos E",
        "E Marcos",
        "Maria  Silva",
        "Maria Silva ",
        " Maria Silva ",
        "Maria silva",
        "maria Silva",
        "MARIA SILVA",
        "MAria Silva",
        "Maria SIlva",
        "Jean-Baptiste",
        "Jeanne d' Arc",
        "Joseph Louis Gay-lussac",
        "Pierre-simon Laplace",
        "Maria daSilva",
        "Maria~Silva",
        "Maria Silva~",
        "~Maria Silva",
        "Maria~ Silva",
        "Maria ~Silva",
        "Maria da da Silva",
        "Maria da e Silva",
        "Maria de le Silva",
        "William Henry Gates iii",
        "Martin Luther King, Jr.",
        "Martin Luther King JR",
        "Martin Luther Jr. King",
        "Martin Luther King Jr. III",
        "Maria G. Silva",
        "Maria G Silva",
        "Maria É Silva",
        "Maria wi Silva",
        "Samuel 'Etoo",
        "Samuel Etoo'",
        "Samuel Eto''o"
    };

    private static void testar(String nome) {
        boolean bom = REGEX_NOME.matcher(nome).matches();
        System.out.println("O nome [" + nome + "] é bom? " + (bom ? "Sim." : "Não."));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Regex: " + NOME_COMPLETO);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Esses nomes devem ser bons:");
        for (String s : NOMES) {
            testar(s);
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Esses nomes devem ser ruins:");
        for (String s : LIXOS) {
            testar(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Esse programa constrói a regex utilizando grupos sem captura (`(?: ... )`), operador de zero-ou-mais vezes (`*`), operador de uma-ou-mais vezes (`+`), operador de uma-ou-nenhuma vez (`?`), início da string (`^`) e final da string (`$`).

[**Veja aqui o programa funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/RAHUkA) Eis a saída desse programa:

```
Regex: ^(?:[\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]])(?:(?:')?(?:[\p{Ll}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]))+(?:\-(?:[\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]])(?:(?:')?(?:[\p{Ll}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]))+)*(?: (?:(?:e|y|de(?:(?: la| las| lo| los))?|do|dos|da|das|del|van|von|bin|le) )?(?:(?:(?:d'|D'|O'|Mc|Mac|al\-))?(?:[\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]])(?:(?:')?(?:[\p{Ll}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]))+|(?:[\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]])(?:(?:')?(?:[\p{Ll}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]))+(?:\-(?:[\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]])(?:(?:')?(?:[\p{Ll}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]))+)*))+(?: (?:Jr\.|II|III|IV))?$

Esses nomes devem ser bons:
O nome [Maria Silva] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Pedro Carlos] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Luiz Antônio] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Albert Einstein] é bom? Sim.
O nome [João Doria] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Barack Obama] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Friedrich von Hayek] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Ludwig van Beethoven] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Jeanne d'Arc] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Saddam Hussein al-Tikriti] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Osama bin Mohammed bin Awad bin Laden] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Luís Inácio Lula da Silva] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Getúlio Dornelles Vargas] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Juscelino Kubitschek de Oliveira] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Jean-Baptiste le Rond d'Alembert] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Pierre-Simon Laplace] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Hans Christian Ørsted] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Joseph Louis Gay-Lussac] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Scarlett O'Hara] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Ronald McDonald] é bom? Sim.
O nome [María Antonieta de las Nieves] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Pedro de Alcântara Francisco António João Carlos Xavier de Paula Miguel Rafael Joaquim José Gonzaga Pascoal Cipriano Serafim] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Luís Augusto Maria Eudes de Saxe-Coburgo-Gota] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Martin Luther King Jr.] é bom? Sim.
O nome [William Henry Gates III] é bom? Sim.
O nome [John William D'Arcy] é bom? Sim.
O nome [John D'Largy] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Samuel Eto'o] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Åsa Ekström] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Gregor O'Sulivan] é bom? Sim.
O nome [Ítalo Gonçalves] é bom? Sim.

Esses nomes devem ser ruins:
O nome [] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria-Silva] é bom? Não.
O nome [Marcos E] é bom? Não.
O nome [E Marcos] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria  Silva] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria Silva ] é bom? Não.
O nome [ Maria Silva ] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria silva] é bom? Não.
O nome [maria Silva] é bom? Não.
O nome [MARIA SILVA] é bom? Não.
O nome [MAria Silva] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria SIlva] é bom? Não.
O nome [Jean-Baptiste] é bom? Não.
O nome [Jeanne d' Arc] é bom? Não.
O nome [Joseph Louis Gay-lussac] é bom? Não.
O nome [Pierre-simon Laplace] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria daSilva] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria~Silva] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria Silva~] é bom? Não.
O nome [~Maria Silva] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria~ Silva] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria ~Silva] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria da da Silva] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria da e Silva] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria de le Silva] é bom? Não.
O nome [William Henry Gates iii] é bom? Não.
O nome [Martin Luther King, Jr.] é bom? Não.
O nome [Martin Luther King JR] é bom? Não.
O nome [Martin Luther Jr. King] é bom? Não.
O nome [Martin Luther King Jr. III] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria G. Silva] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria G Silva] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria É Silva] é bom? Não.
O nome [Maria wi Silva] é bom? Não.
O nome [Samuel 'Etoo] é bom? Não.
O nome [Samuel Etoo'] é bom? Não.
O nome [Samuel Eto''o] é bom? Não.
```

Observe que a regex aceitou todos os nomes que deveria aceitar e rejeitou todos os que deveria rejeitar. A regex produzida é:

> `^(?:[\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]])(?:(?:')?(?:[\p{Ll}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]))+(?:\-(?:[\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]])(?:(?:')?(?:[\p{Ll}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]))+)*(?: (?:(?:e|y|de(?:(?: la| las| lo| los))?|do|dos|da|das|del|van|von|bin|le) )?(?:(?:(?:d'|D'|O'|Mc|Mac|al\-))?(?:[\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]])(?:(?:')?(?:[\p{Ll}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]))+|(?:[\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]])(?:(?:')?(?:[\p{Ll}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]))+(?:\-(?:[\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]])(?:(?:')?(?:[\p{Ll}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]))+)*))+(?: (?:Jr\.|II|III|IV))?$`

Comment: muito legal, aprendi várias coisas novas com este regex. Como estou aprendendo e uso o regex101 ou o regExr, pois possui elementos visuais e facilita o aprendizado, você poderia inserir num site que aceite `[\p{Lu}&&[\p{IsLatin}]]`? Ou fornecer o link de algum que funcione com elementos visuais? Obrigado

Comment: @danieltakeshi Funcionou no http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html - Mas eu tive que alterar uns pequenos detalhes na regex antes para ele aceitar (colocar `\\ ` antes do `-` e agrupar as maiúsculas e minúsculas com `(?:`). Já editei a resposta para refletir isso.

Comment: Muito bem explicado e regex assustadora. Não sei se você concorda, mas validar nomes com tantas regras raramente compensa.

Comment: @bfavaretto Concordo, raramente compensa. E mesmo assim, regex não é a ferramenta que eu normalmente usaria. Mas, gostei do desafio mesmo assim. :)

Comment: `+1` - seria bom indicar no `TL;DR` que a regex é para PHP.

Comment: @Sergio Na verdade, eu fiz em Java. Mas essa regex deve funcionar no PHP.

Comment: @VictorStafusa ok, não conheço as funcionalidades de regex/Java, mas por exemplo JavaScript não há `\p{L}`

Comment: @Sergio Sim. Inicialmente eu tentei fazer com javascript, mas quebrei a cara exatamente por causa disso. Daí, eu tive que fazer em Java.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Não sei se fiz algo errado, mas a validação destes é falsa: "Maria G. Silva","John D'Largy","Martin Luther King Jr.","Samuel Eto'o" porém são nomes muito incomuns na língua portuguesa e não se aplica muito à nós

Comment: @danieltakeshi "*Maria G. Silva*" tem um nome abreviado no meio, então não está correto. "*John D'Largy*" ele esperava como "*d'Largy*". "*Martin Luther King Jr.*" tem um ponto, ele esperava "*Martin Luther King Junior*". Quanto a "*Samuel Eto'o*" e "*William Henry Gates III*", esses são mais difíceis.

Comment: @danieltakeshi Editei a resposta para aceitar esses casos.

Comment: que espetáculo de resposta!

Comment: O imperador do Japão não tem um nome bom :p

Comment: @Renan Sim. Obrigado por dar um caso concreto de alguém com um só nome, o sr. Akihito.

Comment: Olá, gostaria de tirar uma dúvida sobre nomes próprios com apóstrofe, em particular nomes de cidades brasileiras, [D'Água, d'Água ou D'água](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discuss%C3%A3o:Olho_d%27%C3%81gua#D.27.C3.81gua.2C_d.27.C3.81gua_ou_D.27.C3.A1gua.3F)?  "Pau D'Arco" ou  "Pau d'Arco" (TO)?  "Lambari D'Oeste" ou "Lambari d'Oeste" (MT)?  O IBGE adota uma convenção, a prefeitura outra, a Wikipedia outra...

Answer (score 8):

### Regex

O Regex é este (monstro): `^(?![ ])(?!.*[ ]{2})((?:e|da|do|das|dos|de|d'|D'|la|las|el|los)\s*?|(?:[A-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð'][^\s]*\s*?)(?!.*[ ]$))+$`

Em que está habilitado **global, multine e unicode /gmu**

Ou sem caracteres especiais `^(?![ ])(?!.*[ ]{2})((?:e|da|do|das|dos|de|d'|D'|la|las|el|los)\s*?|(?:[A-Z][^\s]*\s*?)(?!.*[ ]$))+$`

Os links para [ReGex101](https://regex101.com/r/NQF5zP/16) e do [Regex Planet](http://fiddle.re/w1xr4d), com a validação dos testes podem ser acessados.

obs.: Está extenso, portanto há espaços para otimizações.

#### Referências

Utilizando estes links do SO global:

- [regular expression for first and last name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385701/regular-expression-for-first-and-last-name)
- [Regular Expression to disallow two consecutive white spaces in the middle of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932323/regular-expression-to-disallow-two-consecutive-white-spaces-in-the-middle-of-a-s)
- [A regex to test if all words are title-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558842/a-regex-to-test-if-all-words-are-title-case)

#### Código gerado pelo Regex101

```js
const regex = /^(?![ ])(?!.*[ ]{2})((?:e|da|do|das|dos|de|d'|D'|la|las|el|los)\s*?|(?:[A-Z][^\s]*\s*?)(?!.*[ ]$))+$/gmu;
const str = `Maria  Silva
Maria silva
maria Silva
MariaSilva
 Maria Silva
Maria Silva 
Maria da Silva
Marina Silva
Maria / Silva
Maria . Silva
Maria Silva
Maria G. Silva
Maria McDuffy
Getúlio Dornelles Vargas
Maria das Flores
John Smith
John D'Largy
John Doe-Smith
John Doe Smith
Hector Sausage-Hausen
Mathias d'Arras
Martin Luther King Jr.
Ai Wong
Chao Chang
Alzbeta Bara
Marcos Assunção
Maria da Silva e Silva
Juscelino Kubitschek de Oliveira
Natalia maria
Natalia aria
Natalia orea
Maria dornelas
Samuel eto'
Maria da Costa e Silva
Samuel Eto'o
María Antonieta de las Nieves`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

## Código em Excel VBA

Como não foi especificado uma linguagem de programação, será demonstrado um modo simples de verificar no Excel a validação do código, já que as outras respostas já contemplam o java.

#### Habilitar o Regex no Excel

1. RegEx precisa ser habilitado, [Habilite o modo Desenvolvedor](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Mostrar-a-guia-Desenvolvedor-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45)
2. Na aba 'Desenvolvedor', clique em 'Visual Basic' e a janela do VBA irá abrir.
3. Vá em 'Ferramentas' -> 'Referências...' e uma janela abrirá.
4. Procure por 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5', como na imagem abaixo. E habilite esta opção.

[image: Janela Referências]

#### Código VBA

```
Dim str As String
Dim objMatches As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Dim i As Long

lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastrow
    str = CStr(Cells(i, 1))
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") 'New regexp
    objRegExp.Pattern = "^(?![ ])(?!.*[ ]{2})((?:e|da|do|das|dos|de|d'|D'|la|las|el|los)\s*?|(?:[A-Z][^\s]*\s*?)(?!.*[ ]$))+$"
    objRegExp.Global = True
    Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(str)
    If objMatches.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each m In objMatches
            ws.Cells(i, 2) = m.Value
            ws.Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Next
    Else
        ws.Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        ws.Cells(i, 2)=""
    End If
Next i
```

#### Resultado

[image: Resultado]

## Código em PCRE

Este é um código feito pelo [ctwheels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3600709/ctwheels) na pergunta [Validate Title Case Full Name with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46608272/validate-title-case-full-name-with-regex).

Em que o código é este:

```
(?(DEFINE)
    (?# Definitions )
    (?<valid_nameChars>[\p{L}\p{Nl}])
    (?<valid_nonNameChars>[^\p{L}\p{Nl}\p{Zs}])
    (?<valid_startFirstName>(?![a-z])[\p{L}'])
    (?<valid_upperChar>(?![a-z])\p{L})
    (?<valid_nameSeparatorsSoft>[\p{Pd}'])
    (?<valid_nameSeparatorsHard>\p{Zs})
    (?<valid_nameSeparators>(?&valid_nameSeparatorsSoft)|(?&valid_nameSeparatorsHard))
    (?# Invalid combinations )
    (?<invalid_startChar>^[\p{Zs}a-z])
    (?<invalid_endChar>.*[^\p{L}\p{Nl}.\p{C}]$)
    (?<invalid_unaccompaniedSymbol>.*(?&valid_nameSeparatorsHard)(?&valid_nonNameChars)(?&valid_nameSeparatorsHard))
    (?<invalid_overTwoUpper>(?:(?&valid_nameChars)*\p{Lu}){3})
    (?<invalid>(?&invalid_startChar)|(?&invalid_endChar)|(?&invalid_unaccompaniedSymbol)|(?&invalid_overTwoUpper))
    (?# Valid combinations )
    (?<valid_name>(?:(?:(?&valid_nameChars)|(?&valid_nameSeparatorsSoft))*(?&valid_nameChars)+(?:(?&valid_nameChars)|(?&valid_nameSeparatorsSoft))*)+\.?)
    (?<valid_firstName>(?&valid_startFirstName)(?:\.|(?&valid_name)*))
    (?<valid_multipleName>(?&valid_firstName)(?=.*(?&valid_nameSeparators)(?&valid_upperChar))(?:(?&valid_nameSeparatorsHard)(?&valid_name))+)
    (?<valid>(?&valid_multipleName)|(?&valid_firstName))
)
^(?!(?&invalid))(?&valid)$
```

E o teste de validação e debug no [Regex 101 aqui](https://regex101.com/r/S1iqsa/1)

Comment: Quando tentei passar sua sugestão de RegEx para meu código esse pattern não foi aceito acusando o seguinte erro: `Multiple markers at this line
- Pattern cannot be resolved. It may lead to runtime erros.
- Groovy:illegal string body character after dollar sign;`

Comment: E outra coisa, `Natalia aria` ele aceita e `Natalia maria` não

Comment: "[*María Antonieta de las Nieves*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mar%C3%ADa_Antonieta_de_las_Nieves)" - Vulgo, chiquinha do Chaves. Esse nome funciona aqui?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Boa, não inseri las, la, el, mas irei alterar

Comment: Um update para tentar tornar à prova de símbolos `/^(?![ ])(?!.*(?:\d|[ ]{2}|[!$%^&*()_+|~=\{\}\[\]:";<>?,\/]))(?:(?:e|da|do|das|dos|de|d'|D'|la|las|el|los|l')\s*?|(?:[A-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð'][^\s]*\s*?)(?!.*[ ]$))+$/`, teste no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NQF5zP/20)

Answer (score 1):

Estive com esse problema para validação de estrutura de nomes, inclusive no meu sistema deve aceitar nomes estrangeiros.

Então consegui compilar uma Regex que atende as seguintes especificações:

1. Pelo menos 2 palavras (nome e sobrenome);
2. Não aceita caracteres especiais, com excessão do "'" apóstrofo
3. Não é case sensitive (pois eu trato no backend)
4. Cada palavra precisa ter no minimo dois caracteres

Segue a Regex

**^((\b[A-zÀ-ú']{2,40}\b)\s*){2,}$**

Pode ser testado em 
https://regex101.com/r/d3Cr6d/2

Answer (score -2):

Somente letras, sem diferenciação de maisculo e minusculo com escapamento de espaço

new RegExp(/^[a-z]{2,}\ [a-z]{2,}/gi).test('Italo Barros')