# Expressão Regular - Nome + Espaço + Sobrenome

Tags: regex

Olá ,estou buscando um expressão regular para validar nome e obrigatoriedade de sobrenome.
Porém ela deve aceitar acentos e um caso especifico  que seria:

Igor D´Sant

Comment: Veja a pergunta [Validar nome e sobrenome com expressão regular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242948/75104)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Validar nome e sobrenome com expressão regular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242948/validar-nome-e-sobrenome-com-express%c3%a3o-regular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex:**

```
^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]+\s+[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]{0,}$
```

**Este regex irá aceitar apenas:**

- letras (case insensitive) com acentos (`\u00C0-\u017F`) ou sem acentos
- o símbolo `´`
- string com pelo menos 1 espaço no meio

**Não irá aceitar:**

- caracteres especiais
- números
- underscore (sublinhado) `_`

**Testando:**

```js
nome1 = "Igor D´Sant"; // normal
nome2 = "IgorD´Sant"; // sem espaço
nome3 = "Igor2 D´Sant"; // com número
nome4 = "Igor D´Sant teste"; // mais de 2 nomes
nome5 = "Igor D´Sánt"; // com acento
nome6 = "Igor D´S-ant"; // com caractere especial
nome7 = "Ig-or D´Sant"; // com caractere especial
nome8 = "Igór D´Sant"; // com acento
nome9 = "Igór_ D´Sant"; // com underscore
nome10 = "Igór"; // apenas 1 nome

if(nome1.match(/^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]+\s+[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]{0,}$/) && nome1.trim().split(' ').length == 2 ){
   console.log(nome1+" = ok");
}else{
   console.log(nome1+" = erro");
}

if(nome2.match(/^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]+\s+[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]{0,}$/) && nome2.trim().split(' ').length == 2 ){
   console.log(nome2+" = ok");
}else{
   console.log(nome2+" = erro");
}

if(nome3.match(/^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]+\s+[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]{0,}$/) && nome3.trim().split(' ').length == 2 ){
   console.log(nome3+" = ok");
}else{
   console.log(nome3+" = erro");
}

if(nome4.match(/^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]+\s+[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]{0,}$/) && nome4.trim().split(' ').length == 2 ){
   console.log(nome4+" = ok");
}else{
   console.log(nome4+" = erro");
}

if(nome5.match(/^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]+\s+[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]{0,}$/) && nome5.trim().split(' ').length == 2 ){
   console.log(nome5+" = ok");
}else{
   console.log(nome5+" = erro");
}

if(nome6.match(/^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]+\s+[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]{0,}$/) && nome6.trim().split(' ').length == 2 ){
   console.log(nome6+" = ok");
}else{
   console.log(nome6+" = erro");
}

if(nome7.match(/^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]+\s+[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]{0,}$/) && nome7.trim().split(' ').length == 2 ){
   console.log(nome7+" = ok");
}else{
   console.log(nome7+" = erro");
}

if(nome8.match(/^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]+\s+[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]{0,}$/) && nome8.trim().split(' ').length == 2 ){
   console.log(nome8+" = ok");
}else{
   console.log(nome8+" = erro");
}

if(nome9.match(/^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]+\s+[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]{0,}$/) && nome8.trim().split(' ').length == 2 ){
   console.log(nome9+" = ok");
}else{
   console.log(nome9+" = erro");
}

if(nome10.match(/^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]+\s+[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]{0,}$/) && nome8.trim().split(' ').length == 2 ){
   console.log(nome109+" = ok");
}else{
   console.log(nome10+" = erro");
}
```

**Teste inserindo nome no campo:**

```js
function verifica(){
   nome = $("#nome").val();
   
   if(nome.match(/^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]+\s+[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F´]{0,}$/) && nome.trim().split(' ').length == 2){
       alert("nome válido");
   }else{
       alert("nome INVÁLIDO");
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="nome" />
<br>
<input type="button" value="Verificar" onclick="verifica()" />
```

Comment: Se eu quiser adicionar mais nome como a expresão ficaria exemplo:  Igor Augusto Siqueira ou Igor Santos Siqueira ou seja adcionar mais um espaço      e string!

Comment: Outro exemplo seria esse nome retirado da nossa base : THERESA LILIANNE DE SA BARRETO DIAZ ALBUQUERQUE SAMPAIO ele teria que passar pela validação

Comment: Esses casos extensos podem ocorrer, mas não precisam ser obrigatórios, mas precisam passar pela validação!

Comment: Com essa expresão que montei aqui consegui liberar de 2 até 60 caracteres, mas não consigo aceitar o Igor D´sant por exemplo :  /(?=^.{2,60}$)^[A-ZÀÁÂĖÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÔÕÙÚÛÇ][a-zàáâãèéêìíóôõùúç]+(?:[ ](?:das?|dos?|de|e|[A-Z][a-z]+))*$/)

Comment: Consegui o seguinte até o momento :  `$.validator.addMethod(
 "NomeCompleto",
 function(value, element, regexp) {
      
  if(value.match(/(?=^.{2,60}$)^[A-ZÀÁÂĖÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÔÕÙÚÛÇ´][a-zàáâãèéêìíóôõùúç´]+(?:[ ](?:das?|dos?|de|e|[A-Z][a-z]+))*$/)){
   return true
  }else{
   return false
}
 },
 "Campo inválido."
);`

Comment: @IgorSiqueira veja este fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qxwx05kf/

Comment: @IgorSiqueira O fiddle vai validar qualquer nome a partir de 2 palavras.

Comment: Perfeito ! Deu certinho !

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que esta simples expressão regular resolva o teu problema:

```
/\w+\s+\w/
```

Exemplo de uso em javascript, por exemplo:

```
/\w+\s+\w/.test('Igor D´Sant'); // retorna true
/\w+\s+\w/.test('Igor'); // retorna false
/\w+\s+\w/.test('Fulano de Tal'); //retorna true
```

Explicação:

`\w+` pega qualquer sentença de palavras digitada.

`\s+` pega qualquer espaço encontrado.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[A-zÀ-ú '´]+$/
```

- `A-zÀ-ú` reconhece todas as letras maiúsculas, minusculas e acentuadas independente do case
- `[A-zÀ-ú '´]` mais espaço e uma das duas formas (`'`) ou (`´`)  de aspas simples permitidos

> se desejar reconhecer apenas uma das formas de aspas é só retirar a indesejada da regex

```js
      var re = /^[A-zÀ-ú '´]+$/ 

      function testInfo(nomeInput){  
        var OK = re.exec(nomeInput.value);  
        if (!OK)  
          console.log(document.getElementById("nome").value + " não é um nome válido!");  
        else
          console.log("Seu nome " + document.getElementById("nome").value + " é válido");  
      }
```

```html
<input id="nome" value="Igor D´Sant">
<button onclick="testInfo(document.getElementById('nome'));">Checar</button>
```