# C# Como faço para evitar que nome composto deixe salvar mais de um espaço?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Essa é minha validação:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome completo é obrigatório.", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-ZáàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ''-'\s]*[a-zA-ZáàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Números e caracteres especiais não são permitidos no nome.")]
[StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Limite máximo de 50 caracteres e limite minimo de 1 caracteres")]
public string Nome { get; set; }
```

Porém nos resultados ela salva por exemplo

```
Ana julia
```

O problema é que também está salvando:

```
Ana      julia
```

Ou seja, está permitindo muitos espaços, queria umsa solução que deixasse só um espaço.

Comment: porque você não inclui no regex pra ele filtrar mais que dois espaços?

Comment: como ? faz isso amigo

Comment: Tire o `\s` de dentro dos colchetes, e deixe apenas um espaço entre as sequências de letras: `^[a-zA-ZáàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ''-']+( [a-zA-ZáàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ]+)*$` - claro que ainda é uma regex ingênua, pois aceita nomes que comecem com `Ç`, por exemplo. Uma regex mais precisa, porém, seria [extremamente complexa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242948/112052), então talvez seja melhor criar um [custom attribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-attributes)

Comment: valeu pela dica do ç, mais o regex não funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Podes sempre fazer desta maneira.
Teres uma string privada para guardar o valor, e ao fazer o set retirares logo os espaços extra.

```
    private string _name;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome completo é obrigatório.", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Limite máximo de 50 caracteres e limite minimo de 1 caracteres")]
    public string Name 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_name != null &&_name.Equals(value))
            {
                return;
            }
            _name = Regex.Replace(value, @"\s+", " ");
        }
    }
```